# Get vue-cli-service test:unit to load environment variables from a different file (not .env.test)

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

Using Vue CLI and Jest. In my packages.config I have:

```
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

From trial and error, I have found that this causes the .env.test environment variable file to load, and sets the NODE_ENV variable to production. This is the the basic test I am testing with:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Home from './Home'

describe('Home', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    console.log('=================================================');
    console.log('ENVVAR=' + process.env.ENVVAR);
    console.log('NODE_ENV=' + process.env.NODE_ENV);
    console.log('=================================================');
    const wrapper = mount(Home);
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately vue-cli-service doesn't have a --mode option when using test:unit. I need to get vue-cli-service to load variables for a specific environment, and also to set NODE_ENV to something specific, for example:

```
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --mode foo",
```

If that existed, I need it to load .env.foo environment variables. Ideally it would change NODE_ENV to foo as well, but that is less concerning.

If I change my packages.config to be:

```
"test:unit": "set NODE_ENV=foo&&vue-cli-service test:unit",
```

It does set NODE_ENV to foo, but vue-cli-service insists on loading .env.test instead of .env.foo. Furthermore, I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
    [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-app> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

    found in

    ---> <App>
           <Root>
```

So is there any way possible to get vue-cli-service to load specific environment variables, and not .env.test?

Thanks

Comment: During testing I forgot I left
NODE_ENV=production
in my .env.test file. Which is interesting because it tells me the NODE_ENV assignment in packages.json takes precedence over the .env file. Not sure how that works. But if I remove NODE_ENV from my .env.test file it does default to 'test' (unlike what I said in my original question).
Also, the errors in my test was caused by not setting up the vuetify context (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/unit-testing). Once I did that, the test works. However Vue insists on loading .env.test instead of another file. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this, I ended up not even using vue-cli-service.

In my packages.json under scripts:

```
"test:unit": "./node_modules/.bin/jest",
```

Then I created this setup.js file:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV='foo';
var dotenv = require("dotenv");
// Load in reverse order (variables in second file will not override variables in first)
dotenv.config({ path: '.env.foo' });
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
```

And referenced it in my jest.config.js:

```js
setupFiles: ["./src/.jest/setup.js"],
```

Proper environment variables now load, and NODE_ENV is set to 'foo' (in this example).